# How to combine two Unordered list using for-each

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach

I have two lists in my page which display similar data, i used for-each to display the list. I it possible to display in a single list

My first List

```
<ul>
@foreach (var item in rpInfo)
{    
<li data-id="@item.ID">
   @item.PartyName
   <ul>
      <li> @item.spName </li>
   </ul>
</li>
}
```

My Second List

```
<ul>
   @foreach (var dRPs in deletedRpHistoryInfo)
   {
   <li data-id="@dRPs.ID">
      @dRPs.PartyName
    <ul>
          <li>@dRPs.spName</li>
   </ul>
   </li>
   }
</ul>
```

I need your help creating a list by combining the the two?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the type of `rpInfo`? `deletedRpHistoryInfo`?

Comment: `var` doesn't tell us the type.

Comment: Do you need any ordering of the combined list? (for ex: first all rpInfo, then all deleteds; sort on PartyName and/or spName) Do you need to know whether a list item was from one list or the other?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Thanks! yes sort by Party Name group by Party Name if more than one spName in rp. thanks!

Comment: @Babish - Any chance you can update your question with the type definitions used?

Comment: If you want to sort and/or combine those lists, you will have to construct a single list first. Maybe the lists share a common basetype that you can use, or you need to construct a viewmodel-type containing just the fields you want to display and sort/group on. *Then* you can use [GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby) to group

Answer (score 4):

At its simplest you don't need two lists, you can simply have the two foreach statements inside the one list...

```
<ul>
foreach(...){
  <li>....</li>
}
foreach(...){
  <li>....</li>
}
</ul>
```

As an aside I'm not sure what value you get embedding the second ul inside the li either.

Comment: Also, a disclaimer: I took "list" to refer to the HTML element UL - not the object being enumerated by the foreach which isn't necessarily a "list" rather is just an IEnumerable ...

Answer (score 1):

I take it your datatypes are similar but not identical, right? Do they inherit from the same parent - or is it maybe worth making them inherit from same parent(if it brings any other benefits). Then you can create new temporary list, typed with the common parent, and merge in both lists.

When foreaching a list with different datatypes in, when accessing a non-common datamember, you need to check what type the current item is.

**Classes:**

```
abstract internal class EmergencyEmployees 
{
    internal string Name { get; set; }
    internal int Age { get; set; }
}

internal class Police : EmergencyEmployees
{
    internal int PoliceLicence { get; set; }
}

internal class Firestarter : EmergencyEmployees
{
    internal int FirestarterLicence { get; set; }
}
```

Program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var officers = new List<Police>();
        var firestarters = new List<Firestarter>();

        officers.Add(new Police { Name = "Kjell", Age = 45, PoliceLicence = 12345 });
        officers.Add(new Police { Name = "Linda", Age = 42, PoliceLicence = 54321 });
        firestarters.Add(new Firestarter { Name = "Arne", Age = 32, FirestarterLicence = 4322 });
        firestarters.Add(new Firestarter { Name = "Anna", Age = 35, FirestarterLicence = 3322 });

        var templist = new List<EmergencyEmployees>();
        templist.AddRange(officers);
        templist.AddRange(firestarters);

        foreach(var ee in templist)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + ee.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Age: " + ee.Age.ToString());
            
            if(ee is Police)
            {
                var p = ee as Police;
                Console.WriteLine("Police Licence: " + p.PoliceLicence.ToString());
            }

            if (ee is Firestarter)
            {
                var p = ee as Firestarter;
                Console.WriteLine("Firestarter Licence: " + p.FirestarterLicence.ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("--------------------");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

[Here](https://www.techiedelight.com/join-two-lists-csharp/) is an article showing several ways that you can do this.

Given your example you could use the .Concat() as that way you keep the original data untouched and keep this all in the foreach loop. This will only work if the type used in both Lists are the same:

```
@foreach (var item in rpInfo.Concat(deletedRpHistoryInfo))
{
   // do stuff
}
```

Comment: @Babish sometimes you can define a common interface for two different types with your used properties. Then you cast rpInfo to the `IEnumerable<TInterface>` before doing the concat.